# Get selected students which checked in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

```
class Student
{
    public Id {get;set;}
    public Name {get;set;} 
}

List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>{st1,st2,st3,st4,st5};
```

DataGridView `dgvStudentName`:

```
(Check)       Id     Name
true          S01    Andrea
false         S02    Mark
true          S03    Selena
true          S04    Bob
false         S05    Mike
```

I tried to get selectList from `studentList` which has DataGridViewCheckBoxCell is true in `dgvStudentName` (checked by user) (Ex: st1,st3,st4).

I used LinQ to get what I want:

```
List<Student> selectList = dgvStudentName.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
              .Where(x=>(bool)x.Cells[0].Value == true)
              .Select(x=>studentList.Where(q=>q.Id)==x.Cell[1].Value.ToString())
              ....
```

But it seems to be a stupid code. Could anyone help me?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: if you had a property on the `Student` class called say `Checked` (boolean) it could be bound to the checked control on the grid.  then you linq would be much easier

Comment: the problem is, this is just a simple Example of my project. the Class "Student" is not able to add more property, and the `dgvStudentName` is checked by user.

Comment: ok, that's a pity. if you could add the property is would not matter that it was checked by the user (that's the whole point of the binding)

Comment: If possible, create a complete new class and with Boolean property in addition to Name and Id properties. And Convert List of Student to the List of new class and bind the list to the DataGridView. Another way is to create a new class inheriting from the Student class and add only one Boolean property to it and Bind the list of new class to the DataGridView.